# What are the possible cases which cause transactions run in parallel within one PostgreSQL session?

Tags: postgresql

I thought about using PostgreSQL advisory locks to prevent some race conditions which can occur when some transactions run in parallel, but the PostgreSQL docs say that the locks only block the other sessions' transactions, not the transactions within one session:

> If a session already holds a given advisory lock, additional requests
>   by it **will always succeed this statement is true regardless of whether**
>   **the existing lock hold and new request are at session level or**
>   **transaction level**

But when do transactions run in parallel within one session? Can I avoid this case somehow without a major performance drop etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when do transactions run in parallel within one session?

Never.

Since version 9.6 there is [intra-query parallelism](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/parallel-query.html), meaning that several CPUs and processes at the OS level may be used in parallel to execute a query, but transactions never execute several queries in parallel, and sessions never spawn several transactions for parallel execution.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is  not specific to Postgres, no relational DBMS supports more than one active transaction on a single connection.